# Execution location for generating thumbnail images from HTML

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

Using .NET, when a user uses an online text editor, and stores the information, we would like to generate a preview image of the HTML that has been created.

So far, as a proof of concept, we have created the image from the HTML and stored this, however, what is the best place for this to be executed (keeping performance in mind).

1. Within the business layer of the application

   - Grab the HTML,
   - Create the image
   - Store the image on the file server
   - Send link of thumbnail, along with the rest of the data to be stored in the database.
2. Create a CLR proc that gets triggered on an insert into the database

   - Generate the Image from the inserted HTML
   - Store the image on the file server
   - Update the database row to store the link to the new thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit here to doing this inside of SQL Server via SQLCLR. There might have possibly been benefit if the data coming into the table was coming from a variety of external sources / apps that couldn't be guaranteed to be using the thumbnail generation routine. But it sounds like the data is coming from a single source that you control. So in this case, it would likely be detrimental to performance to do this in SQLCLR rather than handling it at the app layer (SQL Server is a single source for that processing while app servers can be scaled out).

Also, while you can use any library you like in most .NET environments (WebApp, Windows App, Console App, etc), you are highly restricted to a small subset of .NET Framework libraries ( [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) ) among other restrictions ( [CLR Integration Programming Model Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx) and [Host Protection Attributes and CLR Integration Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403276.aspx) ). And it *might* get really tricky depending on what libraries are being used to generate the image: anything requiring the UI for drawing probably won't work since the UI is inaccessible within SQL Server's CLR host.

Now, there might be benefit to *storing* the thumbnail image in SQL Server in a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column. The benefit is that the thumbnail will be backed up along with the data that it is based upon, and so if the server crashes, you will get the thumbnails back when you restore the database. It also helps ensure that someone, or some other process, doesn't come along and delete one or more thumbnails, which can happen when stored on the file system. And then you also don't need to worry about the cleanup of the file system when the entry is updated or deleted. Of course, it also depends on how many thumbnails you expect and how large they will be. I assume not too large as they are thumbnails.